# is deleting a variable allocated in heap using void pointer a bad thing?

Tags: c++, heap-memory

is there a problem with this code?
I mean the delete statement.

```
int *x = new int;

*x = 13;

void *ptr = x;

delete (int *)ptr;
```

Comment: This code is **not** deleting a heap variable using a *void pointer*.  The C-style `(int*)` cast makes it an *int pointer*.

Comment: Any pointer (other than pointer to member, which is something different) is guaranteed to be able to survive a round-trip via a `void *`.   In that case, it means `(int *)ptr` is equal to `x`, so  `delete (int *) ptr` is equivalent in effect to `delete x`.   After the `delete` expression, dereferencing `x` in any way will have undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you are using an [explicit type conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast), the rules for `static_cast` apply. The relevant rule is in point 10 of [the `static_cast` page @ cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast):

> Conversion of any pointer to pointer to void and back to pointer to the original (or more cv-qualified) type preserves its original value.

In your case, you started with a pointer-to-`int`. You converted that to pointer-to-`void` when you initialized `ptr`. You converted back to pointer-to-`int` in the `delete` statement. This preserves the original value, meaning that both `(int *)ptr` and `x` evaluate to the same address (and have the same type), hence

```
delete (int *)ptr;
```

and

```
delete x;
```

are equivalent. (I'd also add

```
delete static_cast<int*>(ptr);
```

to the list since getting in the habit of using `static_cast` et al. instead of a C-style cast could save you headaches in the future.)

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling `delete` on a `void` pointer in your code. You are turning it back to `int *` before deleting.

Doing the conversions `int *` -> `void *` -> `int *` is guaranteed to give back the original value of the int pointer. So you are basically calling `delete` on the same value returned by `new`. Which is what you are suppose to do.

The issue would be different if you did

```
int *x = new int;
void *ptr = x;
delete ptr;
```

Here `delete` doesn't know that `ptr` is actually supposed to point to an `int`, and has no way of calling any destructors belonging to `int`.  In the case of `int` the destructors probably doesn't do anything, so I can't say fore sure that the code is invalid, maybe someone more versed in c++ could chip in? But for other datatypes with real destructors, that would definitely be an issue.

A small comment at the end: Avoid `new`/`delete`. Use smart pointers and container classes. Only use `new`/`delete` as exercise on how to write smart pointers.

Answer (score 0):

there is nothing wrong with this code, all the memory allocated on the heap is free'd, whether you delete `ptr`  or `x` but not both. Both pointers point to the same address in memory so this is entirely okay; it is safe bet to set free'd pointers = 0 as well!

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

  int* x = new int;
  *x = 13;
  void* ptr = x;

  std::cout << ptr << '\n'; //prints same address
  std::cout << x << '\n'; //prints same address
  
  delete (int*)ptr;
  //delete x;

  ptr = 0;

}
```

Comment: `new`/`delete` are type aware. It is not enough that things point to the same address. In contrast to `malloc`/`free`, type matters. In the case of this code, type matches, so other than that, yes you are right, the code as written is perfectly fine.